# Find $\int\cosh^\frac{1}{2}u~du$ and/or $\int\frac{1}{\cosh^\frac{1}{2}\theta}~d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions, change-of-variable

I am trying to find a function of the form $y=f(x)$ such that the volume of the solid generated by the function between any two points around the $x$ axis is numerically equal to its length bewteen the same $2$ points. Using integrals, we can express this as an equation:
$$\pi\int y^2dx=\int\sqrt{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+1}\quad dx$$
ie
$$\pi y^2=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+1}$$
Rearranging, we get the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\pi^2y^4-1}$$
I tried to solve this first by separating the variables:
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi^2y^4-1}}~dy=x+c$$
So the next step is obviously to find
$$I=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi^2y^4-1}}~dy$$
Now here lies the problem. I tried to go about this using $2$ methods, each using different substitutions:

**1.**

Let $\pi y^2=\cosh u$:
$$\sinh u\frac{du}{dy}=2\pi y\implies dy=\frac{1}{2\pi y}\sinh{u}~ du$$
$$\implies I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\frac{1}{y}du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi^3}}\int\cosh^\frac{1}{2}u~du$$
How can I find the following?
$$\int\cosh^\frac{1}{2}u~du$$
**2.**

Using the substitutions $\pi y^2=p$ followed by $p=\cosh \theta$ gives us the result
$$I=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int\frac{1}{\cosh^\frac{1}{2}\theta}~d\theta$$
Again, how I can I find the following?
$$\int\frac{1}{\cosh^\frac{1}{2}\theta}~d\theta$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I doubt there exists a closed-form solution; [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%28cosh%28x%29%29+dx) returns the result of your first being an elliptic integral.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer thanks, that's very interesting. So there is no (elementary) curve that satisfies my criteria.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I do not consider elliptic integrals not closed-form, merely non-elementary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, there is no solution with elementary functions. However, if you have Byrd and Friedman – the great big book of elliptic integrals and functions – this problem falls very easily.

The second integral $\int\cosh^{-1/2}\theta\,d\theta$ is the slightly easier one to tackle, for B&F 296.00 gives
$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{\cosh\theta}}\,d\theta=\sqrt2F\left(\cos^{-1}\frac1{\sqrt{\cosh\theta}},m=\frac12\right)+K$$
Substituting $\cosh\theta=\pi y^2$ gives
$$I=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}F\left(\cos^{-1}\frac1{y\sqrt\pi},\frac12\right)+K$$

Comment: You've now answered both of the questions I've asked within the last 2 days :)